# Excel 2010 VBA: Invalid procedure call when adding data field to pivot table

Tags: vba, runtime-error, excel-2010, pivot-table

I want to create multiple pivot tables by encapsulating the complexity into functions and procedures (I did already manage to create pivots with VBA, but one module  for each pivot, meaning lots of repetitive code...)

I managed to create procedures and functions to create the pivot, add a filter, and a row field. But when it comes to adding a data field, I get an invalid procedure call; the strange thing however is that I get that error only when I use variables to pass info: looking at the line prodicung the error, the first line works perfectly fine, whereas I cannot get the second line running (the variables contain the correct values):

```
 pivotName.addDataField pivotName.PivotFields("sdID"), "SD ID number", xlCount 'works fine
 pivotName.addDataField pivotName.PivotFields(fieldName), fieldDescription, calcMethod 'produces Invalid procedure call error
```

As I am running out of ideas, any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you very much,

Alexander

Comment: Could you try to enter the 3 variables separately, to determine whether only one of them causes the problem? Maybe one of them is of the wrong datatype.

Comment: What are you declaring your variables as? At a guess it'll be the `calcMethod` variable which I believe should be declared as `XLConsolidationFunction`

Comment: Thank you Dan, in general a good tip, I was already too tired to think of that myself...

Comment: @ Gareth: Thank you very much, that in fact was the problem! I declared `calcMethod` as string, which obviously caused the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is due to `calcMethod` being declared earlier in the code as a `string`.

The `.addDataField` method accepts the following parameters:

```
.AddDataField(Field, Caption, Function)
```

The parameter `Function` is of the `XLConsolidationFunction` enum and therefore should be declared and assigned like below:

```
Dim calcMethod As XlConsolidationFunction

calcMethod = xlCount
```

Once declared and assigned as above, you can use it within your method in the following way where `fieldName` and `fieldDescription` are both strings:

```
pivotName.addDataField pivotName.PivotFields(fieldName), fieldDescription, calcMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the comment from Gareth, the problem was to declare `calcMethod` (optional function) as string, not as XLConsolidatedFunction.

Thank you once again!